# git 'rebase' behaving differently to 'pull --rebase'

Tags: git, version-control

I have a git repository with a develop branch which is tracking an upstream origin/develop branch. I have added a single commit on develop, and meanwhile origin/develop has moved forwards by about 30 commits.

If I run `git fetch`, and then `git rebase origin/develop`, everything seems to be OK, my single commit is above origin/develop and I have one commit to push.

If I instead run `git pull --rebase`, develop moves to the same commit as origin/develop, and my commit has disappeared.

I thought `git pull --rebase` was exactly the same as `git fetch origin && git rebase`. What gives?

Comment: "and my commit has disappeared" --- I don't believe it.

Comment: OK, when I say my commit has disappeared, I mean there is no branch pointing at it. I can get back to the commit with the reflog.

Comment: It should be in reflog indeed because `rebase` does not drop it physically, but I'm surprised that your changes are not re-applied to the `HEAD` of the `origin/develop`. Do your changes interfere anyhow with changes made by another developer?

Comment: Me too! No, there are no conflicts when I rebase.